# using loaded libraries within imported functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter Notebook where I load functions and classes from a utils.py file.

On top of my Notebook, all required libraries are loaded (pandas, numpy etc.).

Now, when I call a function which was imported from utils.py, and uses pandas within, I get a

`NameError: name 'pd' is not defined`

Do I need to import all standard libraries again within utils.py / the loaded functions, or is it somewhat possible to reuse what was imported in the main notebook?

Thanks

**Edit:**

utils.py:

```
def myFunction():
    pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
from utils import myFunction

myFunction()
```

this throws the exception.

As highlighted below, you need to import pandas also in utils.py:

```
import pandas as pd
def myFunction():
    pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Yes, you need to import pandas in utils

Comment: Thanks Juanpa, that works. I just was wondering if I'm doing something wrong. If you want please anwer this question and I will accept.

Comment: @Prune, I found the question trivial to go without example. But will add one for later readers.

Answer (score 1):

Answering based on Juanpa's suggestion:

You need to import all modules also in the loaded function file.
E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
def myFunction():
    pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```